# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ if $a_n>0 \ \forall n\in \mathbf{N}$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ converges and $b_n$ bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, upper-lower-bounds

Let $(a_n)$ a sequence such that $a_n>0 \ \forall n\in \mathbf{N}$. Suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ converges and the sequence $(b_n)$ is bounded. Show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges.

I would like to have a feedback on my proof and to know if everything holds. Thanks in advance.

*Proof.*

First of all, as  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, we can note that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$. So, $\exists N \ \forall n\ge N$: $0<a_n<1$ .

Then, as $(b_n)$ is a bounded sequence, we have by definitiot that:

$\exists M>0: \ |b_n|\le M \ \forall n\in \mathbf{N}$.

With all these preliminary results we can write that:

$|b_n|\le M \iff |b_n|\cdot a_n\le M\cdot a_n \underbrace{\iff}_{a_n>0 \ \forall n} |b_na_n|\le M|a_n|$.

As $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ converges and $a_n>0 \ \forall n \in \mathbf{N}$ (so there is no difference between $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|$), $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|$ converges and so $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}M|a_n|$ too.

By comparaison we conclude that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges absolutely so it converges.

Comment: You don't need the two lines just after Proof.

Comment: @Ryan Shesler but as $a_n>0$ it holds no? If i didn't have that hypothesis i should have written $0<|a_n|<1$

Comment: @archuser Sorry I missed where it said $a_n > 0$, my bad. Your argument looks good to me.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Oh yes of course... First i was trying to resolve using the inequality with $a_n$ so forgot to remove that from my paper x) Thank you!

Comment: @Ryan Shesler Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. You can use Cauchy criterion.

Assume $ M>0$.
Given $ \epsilon>0$,

For $ m $ and $ n $ large enough
$$|\sum_{k=n}^ma_k|=\sum_{k=n}^ma_k< \frac{\epsilon}{M}$$
and
$$|\sum_{k=n}^ma_kb_k|\le M\sum_{k=n}^ma_k<\epsilon$$

This proves the convergence of the series $\sum a_nb_n$.

Comment: Thank you for an alternative solution!